# C++ error tracking unexpected token

Tags: c++

After some refactoring and changes to a C++ class, an error occured. The strange thing is that the error is not located in my .cpp file, but in an external include file (OpenSceneGraph) which worked fine until now.

In the osg/Object file there is the following enum

```
enum DataVariance
{
    DYNAMIC,
    STATIC,
    UNSPECIFIED
};
```

which results in a syntax error. When I change `STATIC` to `STATIc`, everything compiles fine.

> error C2059: syntax error: 'static '
>
> error C3805: 'Typ': unexpected token, expected either '}' or ','

I didn't change a thing in OpenSceneGraph, only refactored some code in a class using OpenSceneGraph and the error suddenly appeared.
The whole compiler output talks about errors in the external code.

How can I extract the real point of failure in my own code from the compiler output? I think it's just something stupid, but I have no idea where to search for the mistake.

(I can't just change the code of OpenSceneGraph)

Comment: the file I edited is very old and badly written and has over 3000 lines, so I would be thankful about a hint what could cause the error

Comment: Looks like there might be a `#define STATIC static` somewhere.

Comment: I thought about that, too, but searching the whole project doesn't reveal another occurence of `STATIC`

Comment: @NathanOliver's explanation is the only one that makes sense. You can try to capture the output of just preprocessing the file (using -E in g++) and verify whether that's true or not.

Comment: Try declaring a `static` variable somewhere using `STATIC`. See if it compiles.

Comment: How about using VAR_STATIC, VAR_DYNAMIC, VAR_xxx as enum entries?

Comment: This is exactly why using compile time constants in UPPERCASE is antipattern. Look into preprocessor output what happens there. Notice preprocessor macros can be supplied through compiler parameters, so do not look in files, but check prerpocessed file.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is name collision with preprocessor problem. This is why old habbit of having all constant in uppercase creates problems this days instead of fixing them. To fix this issue remove macro definition before include:

```
#ifdef STATIC
#undef STATIC
#endif
#include <header_with_problem>
```

on another side undefining this macro may create problems somewhere else, you then need to find what value it has and restore it after include. (or put this include as last one if possible)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as stupid as I expected it to be:

I used clang-format to format my code according to the guideline. The clang-format tool changed the include file order (alphabetical, whoever set this property). That "minor" change broke my code.

Hint: I used the preprocessor to solve the problem:

```
#if 0
// excluded code
#endif
```

and

```
#if 1
// included code
#endif
```

This allowed me to exclude codeparts. If the compilation still fails it will be a problem of the rest of the code. So I found out, that the problem was hidden in some include file.

Afterwards I used SVN Diff to compare the includes.

Comment: There should be no dependency on the order of include directives. In my view any such dependency is a bug.

Comment: there might be a minor difference between "should be" and "cannot be". That kind of dependency is very unpleasant, but somehow inevitable if you deal with many external headers.

If you once come to the point where you have to use those libraries, you have to deal with the fact that some of those programmers weren't careful enough while coding